# More efficient way of pulling specific value from dozens of variations of specific webpage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets to pull a single value from dozens of iterations of a webpage. The URL is nearly identical for each page, besides a changing User ID and a number for the specific month.

My function currently sets a cell equal to an IMPORTXML formula, containing variables to account for the changes. However, I eventually will have over 600 requests that need done, and Google Sheets tends to take forever/break when doing that many requests.

This data will only need to be pulled once a month.

```
    var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var uniqueSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

    var uniqueLastColumn = uniqueSheet.getLastColumn() + 1;

    var players = [654270, 601000, 335700, 636969, 344585];
  var numPlayers = players.length;

    var currPlayer = 0;
  var row = 1;

    var currMonth = 0;
    var maxMonth = 12;

    for (currPlayer = 0; currPlayer < numPlayers; currPlayer++) {
        

        for (currMonth = 0; currMonth < maxMonth; currMonth++) {

            tarRange = uniqueSheet.getRange(row, (uniqueLastColumn + currMonth)).setValue('=importXML("https://www.trueachievements.com/gamerperiodsummary.aspx?gamerid=' + players[currPlayer] + '&year=2021&month=' + currMonth + '", "/html/body/form/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[1]") ');
        }

        row++;
        uniqueLastColumn = 1;
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to pull this data?

I tried other variations, including not using XmlService, however, I was unable to find a way to grab only the data I need.

I need the value in a specific  tag, set up like this.

```
<div class ="gs-rd">
      <div></div>
      <div>
             <span> **THIS ONE IS THE ONE I NEED** </span>
             <span></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the function `IMPORTXML` but this way to fill cells is terribly wrong:

```
for (currPlayer = 0; currPlayer < numPlayers; currPlayer++) {
    for (currMonth = 0; currMonth < maxMonth; currMonth++) {
        tarRange = uniqueSheet.getRange(row, (uniqueLastColumn + currMonth))
        .setValue('=importXML("https://www.trueachievements.com/gamerperiodsummary.aspx?gamerid=' 
        + players[currPlayer] + '&year=2021&month=' 
        + currMonth + '", "/html/body/form/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[1]") ');
    }
    row++;
    uniqueLastColumn = 1;
}
```

You need to make a 2D-array first and fill cells in one step with `range.setValues(array)` method.

Something like this:

```
var tarRange_all = uniqueSheet.getRange(1,1,100,100); // put here your real range

var s1 = '=importXML("https://www.trueachievements.com/gamerperiodsummary.aspx?gamerid=';
var s2 = '&year=2021&month=';
var s3 = '", "/html/body/form/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[1]") ';

var table = []; // the array

for (currPlayer = 0; currPlayer < numPlayers; currPlayer++) {
    var table_row = [];
    for (currMonth = 0; currMonth < maxMonth; currMonth++) {
        table_row.push(s1 + players[currPlayer] + s2 + currMonth + s3);
    }
    table.push(table_row);
}

tarRange_all.setValues(table); // fill all cells at once
```

Every `setValue()` or `getValue()` takes ages to execute. You shall use it as few as it possible.